# Baggage and check-ins on different airlines

Tags: luggage, layovers

The airlines are British Airways and American Airlines (which, from what I understand, are partners).  A friend bought my mother and I our tickets for our trip from Cairo (CAI) `->` Philadelphia (PHL) with a layover in London (LHR), which were booked through American Airlines.

My problem is, when I overviewed the confirmation and receipt with the baggage information, all it said under "Checked Bags / British Airways" was that the 1st bag is free and the 2nd is $85.  And our friend said he could only buy 2 bags for my mother and I (one for me, one for her), which I'm guessing are those 2nd bags, which means this would apply per passenger if my thinking is correct (so `Passenger = 1st bag (free) + 2nd bag ($85)` and this applies to each?).

Second, I need to know what we need to do for when we arrive in London, like, do we need to collect our bags and re-check them?  If so, will we need to pay more fees or not?

Comment: If the entire trip is on a single ticket issued by AA, then without any doubt your bags will be "checked through" and transferred to your next flight in London without you ever seeing them.

Comment: Are the two legs separate bookings, or do they appear under a single Record Locator? What country's (or countries') passports do you and your mother carry?

Answer (score 1):

The British Airways webpage is telling you that you may check one bag for free, but your checking a second bag will cost $85.00. The same is true for your mother. Thus, if you and your mother each check one bag, there should be no additional charge for the checked baggage.

Because both flights appear on one booking, the airline (presumably BA) that carries you from Cairo to London will tag your bags for Philadelphia, and in London the bags will be transferred by BA to the airplane that will carry you to the US. You will not need to retrieve your bags in London and re-submit them for carriage to the US.

According to [this UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa?step-by-step-nav=d8f3c2e0-d544-4664-9616-ab71323e4d18), you will not need a transit visa to wait in the airport in London to catch your flight to the US. You will not pass through UK immigration and customs in London, but will pass through US immigration and customs upon arrival in the US.

Comment: We're both American citizens, so we carry American passports.  Both the receipt and confirmation are American Airlines.

Comment: How much time will elapse between arriving in Heathrow, and departing on the flight to Philadelphia? Do you intend to leave the airport?

Comment: It's about a 2 hour layover, then we leave for Philly.

Comment: I've amended the answer to reflect the additional info you've provided.

Comment: Alright, awesome!  Thanks.  I feel a lot more calm. lol

Comment: You're welcome. I notice that you didn't answer the query about whether the tickets were issued in a single transaction, i.e., with a single Record Locator. My answer assumes this from your statement that the tickets were all booked through American Airlines. Were they in fact issued under a single Record Locator? If they were not, then my answer is not correct.

Comment: There was only one record locator in the confirmation and receipt page.  I saw no other record locators.